# Допустимы ли в научных публикациях такие конструкции?

Tags: грамотная-речь, оформление-текста

В квадратных скобках указаны источники из списка литературы.

*В [9] рассмотрены также принципы организации реабилитационных учреждений, требования к кадрам...*

*Это только один из симптомов, к которому может быть применено любое определение из [14, 15, 23].*

С языковой точки зрения такие предложения, мягко говоря, плохо читаются. Я бы не стал так писать. Допустимо ли это в научной литературе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне сложно дать оценку по такому критерию как "языковая допустимость", но могу сказать, что такая пунктуация в научной литературе (особенно электронной, с активными гиперссылками) применяется повсеместно.
Более того, лично я уже настолько привык к подобной пунктуации, что мне даже трудно предположить, чем можно было бы ее заменить, не проиграв в наглядности и лаконичности.

Answer (score 0):

Да, довольно странная пунктуация, так как в скобки берутся различные отступления, комментарии, вставки, а тут в скобки взят член предложения — обстоятельство.